# Ruby: Cannot load such file from - LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a ruby script file with the name test.rb.

the file has the following two require statements:

```
require 'oauth'
require 'HTTParty'
```

I have the two gems already installed before.

when running **ruby test.rb** in the terminal I get the following error:

> /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- HTTParty (LoadError)
>           from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>           from test.rb:2:in `'

what can be wrong here?

Comment: Normally, it would be successful, you may double check whether those gems were installed for `ruby-2.0.0-p598`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with Ruby commands, how to check if the gems are installed for ruby 2.0.0-p598?

Comment: This is a terminal command, not a ruby command. So just run it on your command line. Gem is a separate program that manages your ruby gems.

Comment: I checked with gem list --local and found that the two gems are installed, what can be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case matters.

`require 'httparty'`

Comment: Exactly, what a naive mistake, changing require 'HTTParty' to require 'httparty' solved it, thanks a lot